# Какое событие элемента WebView соответствует событию Navigated элемента WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, webview, windows-phone-8

Есть ли аналог события `Navigated` элемента управления `WebBrowser` (WindowsForms) для элемента управления `WebView` (Windows Phone 8.1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, вам нужно событие [`NavigationCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationcompleted.aspx). Оно происходит, когда контрол завершает загрузку контента или если во время загрузки происходит ошибка.